Python and Excel: Putting data into another function then getting back information from it
I am attempting to put temperature/pressure data into Steam Table for superheated enthalpy data. 
I have successfully grabbed the data and put it into the excel file, then it pulls then enthalpy data for me.
The issue is, when I put the temperature and pressure data into the steam table, it doesn't actually do the double interpolation and therefore the enthalpy (H) value never actually changes. I end up just getting the original value given in the steam data. 
Is there a way I can make it put the data into the file then hit "enter" so it can do the double interpolation then I can grab the values?
Here is my work so far:
import openpyxl

def process_excel_files(input_file, process_file, output_file, data_sheet_name, process_sheet_name, result_sheet_name, input_columns, result_column, start_row=1):
    # Load the workbooks
    input_wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(input_file)
    process_wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(process_file, data_only=True)
    output_wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(output_file)

    # Select the sheets
    data_sheet = input_wb[data_sheet_name]
    process_sheet = process_wb[process_sheet_name]
    result_sheet = output_wb[result_sheet_name]

    # Iterate through each row in the data_sheet
    for row in range(start_row, data_sheet.max_row + 1):
        # Read data points from the data_sheet
        PressurePSI = data_sheet.cell(row=row, column=input_columns[0]).value #steam Pressure in PSI
        TemperatureF = data_sheet.cell(row=row, column=input_columns[1]).value #Stean Temperature in F
        # Convert read data points from the data_sheet
    #    PressureMPA=PressurePSI*0.00689476 #Steam Pressure in MPA
      #  TemperatureC=(TemperatureF-32)*(5/9) #Steam Temperature in C
        # Input data points into the process_sheet
        process_sheet.cell(row=8, column=3).value = PressurePSI
        process_sheet.cell(row=8, column=4).value = TemperatureF
        # Save the process_wb to update the process_sheet
        process_wb.save(process_file)

        # Reload the output_wb to get the updated value
        process_wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(process_file)
        process_sheet = process_wb[process_sheet_name]

        # Retrieve the result from the process_sheet
        result_value = process_sheet.cell(row=8, column=7).value  # Assuming the result is in cell G8

        # Write the result into the result_sheet
        result_sheet.cell(row=row, column=result_column).value = result_value

    # Save the output_wb to update the result_sheet
    output_wb.save(output_file)

# Usage example:
input_file = 'TempPressVals.xlsx'
process_file = 'Steam_Tables.xlsx'
output_file = 'EnthalpyValues.xlsx'
data_sheet_name = 'Sheet1'
process_sheet_name = 'Sheet1'
result_sheet_name = 'Sheet1'
input_columns = [1, 2]  # Columns A and B
result_column = 1  # Column C

process_excel_files(input_file, process_file, output_file, data_sheet_name, process_sheet_name, result_sheet_name, input_columns, result_column)

Here is my fixed code complete:
import xlwings as xw
import os

def process_excel_files(input_file, process_file, output_file, data_sheet_name, process_sheet_name, result_sheet_name, input_columns, result_column, start_row=1):
    # Start a new Excel instance
    with xw.App(visible=False) as app:
        app.display_alerts = False
        app.screen_updating = False

        # Load the workbooks
        input_wb = app.books.open(input_file)
        process_wb = app.books.open(process_file)
        output_wb = app.books.open(output_file)

        # Select the sheets
        data_sheet = input_wb.sheets[data_sheet_name]
        process_sheet = process_wb.sheets[process_sheet_name]
        result_sheet = output_wb.sheets[result_sheet_name]

        # Iterate through each row in the data_sheet
        for row in range(start_row, data_sheet.range('A1').end('down').row + 1):
            # Read data points from the data_sheet
            PressurePSI = data_sheet.range((row, input_columns[0])).value  # Steam Pressure in PSI
            TemperatureF = data_sheet.range((row, input_columns[1])).value  # Steam Temperature in F

            # Input data points into the process_sheet
            process_sheet.range('C8').value = PressurePSI
            process_sheet.range('D8').value = TemperatureF

            # Save and close the process_wb to update the process_sheet
            process_wb.save()
            process_wb.close()  # Close the workbook to force recalculation
            process_wb = app.books.open(process_file)  # Re-open the workbook
            process_sheet = process_wb.sheets[process_sheet_name]

            # Retrieve the result from the process_sheet
            result_value = process_sheet.range('G8').value  # Assuming the result is in cell G8

            # Write the result into the result_sheet
            result_sheet.range((row, result_column)).value = result_value

        # Save and close the workbooks
        input_wb.save()
        output_wb.save()

        input_wb.close()
        process_wb.close()
        output_wb.close()

# Usage example:
input_file = 'TempPressVals.xlsx'
process_file = 'Steam_Tables.xlsx'
output_file = 'EnthalpyValues.xlsx'
data_sheet_name = 'Sheet1'
process_sheet_name = 'Sheet1'
result_sheet_name = 'Sheet1'
input_columns = [1, 2]  # Columns A and B
result_column = 2  # Column C

process_excel_files(input_file, process_file, output_file, data_sheet_name, process_sheet_name, result_sheet_name, input_columns, result_column)


Second , Openpyxl is an XML editor for want of a better description. It does not use Excel and therefore no data in a Sheet other than what you physically write to a cell will be updated until the workbook is opened in Excel. I.e formulas, links etc are not evaluated. There are some module that may be able to do this separately without Excel if running that app is a problem but otherwise perhaps a module that uses Excel like Xlwings or Win32com would be better.

Thank you for the insight! I am jumping in and learning about both Xlwings and Win32com.

XLwings worked great, thank you!
